# how to hide a column in database

Tags: database, sqlite

This is my original code:

```
String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM data where company = '"+ Selecteditem +"'"  ;

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);

if (c.moveToFirst()){
   do{
      temp_array.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")) +
                     "," + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("code")) +
                     "," + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("company")) 
                    );
```

I want to hide company on the list, I change "*****" to `name, code` but without success, I delete `" **"," + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("company"))** "` this line no success,

What to do please help me

Comment: Instead of using Select * from table you might want to use something like Select Column1, Column2, etc, from table... Improves performance and makes the column indices fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the company string, by replacing `c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("company"))` with an empty string `""`.

```
String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM data where company = '" + Selecteditem + "'";

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);

if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        temp_array.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")) +
            "," + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("code")) +
            "," + ""
        );
```

Another solution is to select only the columnn you need:

```
String sqlQuery = "SELECT name, code FROM data where company = '" + Selecteditem + "'";

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);

if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        temp_array.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")) +
            "," + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("code"))
        );
```