# selecting table columns without one

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a problem with selecting Sqlite query:

```
$ Select '"+tablica+"'.* from '"+tablica+"',sqlite_master where sqlite_master.name='"+tablica+"' ; $
```

What it does is that it gets table data from my online Sqlite database, but I need it to show every column except 1st one ( my database columns: first one is called the same as the table and its my primary key, and other columns are like "Period" "Demand" etc. So what i really need to get from select are all those other columns except first one. That "tablica" represents what my combox says so it switches between tables. How can I remake the code without (with) that *from... To not select * (all) but everything except 1st column

Comment: You need to list out the columns you want in the `select`.

Comment: yea but how can I do it with "tablica".* 
what is my  condition for select everything except 1st column?

Comment: You can't. There's no way in SQL to achieve what you want without explicitly enumerating the columns.

Comment: Is there any way to set it to invisible when im trying to show whole table?

Comment: Apparently not. Please note that this question has been asked before - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22893397/how-to-hide-a-column-in-database

Comment: @MarkoPetrePetričević how are you planning to present the info to the user? Use this to 'hide' the primary key column, the. You can even add a show / hide Pk button on your nterface, which in my mind would be better from user experience.